# Remove words from pyspark dataframe based on words from another pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to remove the words in main data frame from secondary data frame.

This is the main data frame:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|  event_dt|           cust_text|
+----------+--------------------+
|2020-09-02|hi fine i want to go|
|2020-09-02|i need  a line hold |
|2020-09-02|i have the  60 packs|
|2020-09-02|hello want you teach|
```

Below is single-column secondary data frame. The words in the secondary data frame need to be removed from the main data frame in column `cust_text` wherever the words occur. For example, `'want'` will be removed from every row wherever it shows up in the main data frame (in this example will be removed from 1st and 4th row).

```
+-------+
|column1|
+-------+
|   want|
|because|
|   need|
|  hello|
|      a|
|   have|
|     go|
+-------+
```

The `event_dt` column will remain as is and each row will remain as is, only the secondary data frame words are removed from main data frame in the result data frame as shown below

```
+----------+--------------------+
|  event_dt|           cust_text|
+----------+--------------------+
|2020-09-02|hi fine i to        |
|2020-09-02|i line hold         |
|2020-09-02|i the 60 packs      |
|2020-09-02|you teach           |
+----------+--------------------+
```

Help is appreciated!!

Comment: can u pls check and let me know the solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the working solution for you - Use **`array_except()`** in order to eliminate the unwanted strings, however in order to do that, we need to do a little bit of preparation.

## Create the DataFrame Here

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2020-09-02","hi fine i want to go"),("2020-09-02","i need  a line hold"), ("2020-09-02", "i have the  60 packs"), ("2020-09-02", "hello want you teach")],[ "col1","col2"])
```

## **Make the column as Array for future use**

```
df = df.withColumn("col2", F.split("col2", " "))
df.show(truncate=False)
df_lookup = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"want"),(1,"because"), (1, "need"), (1, "hello"),(1, "a"),(1, "give"), (1, "go")],[ "col1","col2"])
df_lookup.show()
```

## Output

```
+----------+---------------------------+
|col1      |col2                       |
+----------+---------------------------+
|2020-09-02|[hi, fine, i, want, to, go]|
|2020-09-02|[i, need, , a, line, hold] |
|2020-09-02|[i, have, the, , 60, packs]|
|2020-09-02|[hello, want, you, teach]  |
+----------+---------------------------+

+----+-------+
|col1|   col2|
+----+-------+
|   1|   want|
|   1|because|
|   1|   need|
|   1|  hello|
|   1|      a|
|   1|   give|
|   1|     go|
+----+-------+
```

## Now, just groupBy the lookup dataframe and take all the lookup values in a variable as below

```
df_lookup_var = df_lookup.groupBy("col1").agg(F.collect_set("col2").alias("col2")).collect()[0][1]
print(df_lookup_var)
x = ",".join(df_lookup_var)
print(x)
df = df.withColumn("filter_col", F.lit(x))
df = df.withColumn("filter_col", F.split("filter_col", ","))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

## This does the trick

```
df = df.withColumn("ArrayColumn", F.array_except("col2", "filter_col"))
df.show(truncate = False)
+----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
|col1      |col2                       |filter_col                               |ArrayColumn                |
+----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
|2020-09-02|[hi, fine, i, want, to, go]|[need, want, a, because, hello, give, go]|[hi, fine, i, to]          |
|2020-09-02|[i, need, , a, line, hold] |[need, want, a, because, hello, give, go]|[i, , line, hold]          |
|2020-09-02|[i, have, the, , 60, packs]|[need, want, a, because, hello, give, go]|[i, have, the, , 60, packs]|
|2020-09-02|[hello, want, you, teach]  |[need, want, a, because, hello, give, go]|[you, teach]               |
+----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Fantastic!!  It worked. I added one thing because the list of secondary dataframe is more than 7000 words.

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df_lookup = df.withColumn('col1', lit('1'))
df.show(5)

Comment: array_except() removes the duplicates from within the source. I don't want that.

Comment: @ dsk, array_except() removes the duplicates of within the source. I don't want that. Any idea how to fix that?